# Custom title image in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've successfully got a three-tab, styled implementation of ActionBarSherlock running in my project. Given the myriad of things ActionBarSherlock does, I'm wondering if ABS has the ability to set a custom title image such as Foursquare or GroupMe.

[image: GroupMe]

[image: foursquare]

I imagine they are running a custom implementation of the actionbar, but I just thought it might be easy enough to replicate in ABS.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is really easy actually, just do this in your OnCreate:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.foo);
```

Comment: Easy enough indeed!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's looking for a way to change the ActionBar icon using XML, here it is:

In styles.xml, you'd have to create a custom style for the ActionBar widget

```
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_custom_icon_goes_here</item>
    </style>
```

Then make a custom theme that extends one of the default themes (or the Sherlock themes), and specify the custom ActionBar style

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBar</item>
</style>
```